# No results returned by a query, is this a string format issue ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript.

The below code should enable me to query a user inputted string against the parse.com db and return results. I know there are results that exist, but it seems like the string is not being captured in a format that is being interpreted correctly?

****Parse.com query using JavaScript that should search the class "myBadges" and the "das" column for the string "friendName**

```
var myBadgeUploader = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

function friendFeed() {

    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadgeUploader);
    query.startsWith("das", friendName);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          console.log(results);
           }
    });
}
```

---

****Code that should capture the "FriendName" in a string to be used in the query**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).on('click','.username', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        friendName = $(this).text();
        console.log(friendName);
        friendFeed();
    });
});
```

**Code that creates the list of users and the username to be clicked.**

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();  
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
query.include('toUser');
// query.include('fromUser');
//query.include('pic');
query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        Username = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            var object = results[i].get("toUser");
            imageURLs.push(object.get("pic"));
            Username.push(object.get("username"));
        }


        // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        console.log(imageURLs);
        console.log(Username);
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {  
            $('#container').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
            $('#container').append("<div class='username'>'"+Username[j]+"'</div>"); }

    },
    error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

});
```

[image]

Comment: `friendFeed` doesn't have a `success:` function, so it doesn't do anything with the results.

Comment: @Barmar should the results still not show in the Chrome console log though under responses ? I added the success: function and still no results are returned.

Comment: Are they the same question? This question says that nothing is being returned, your new question says that too much is being returned.

Comment: @Barmar they were based around the same issue, the wrong results being returned depending on how the query was set up. I fel like their was some duplication between them